# Selenium Nodejs CHROMEDRIVER path

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Tried with "npm install selenium-webdriver" I'm still getting the error below. Any idea where the path is sops to be at?

```
Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at new ServiceBuilder (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:51:11)
    at getDefaultService (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:216:22)
    at new Driver (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:470:32)
    at Builder.build (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:302:14)
    at Object.handle (/var/www/nodejs/node.js:31:4)
    at next_layer (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok assuming you are using Windows please try the following steps:

- Download the latest version of ChromeDriver from here [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
- Extract the zip and place the contents somewhere you know where it is for example "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\ChromeDriver"
- Go to your Control Panel -> System -> Edit the System Variables. Click on the "environment variables" button.
- In the system variables box there will be a variable named "Path" select it and click edit. Copy and paste the path to the containing directory of the chromedriver.exe you downloaded onto the end of the variable value and end it with a semi-colon.
- Click ok and again to close environment variables and again to close system properties.
- Close and reopen your terminal window.
- Run the command again.

I hope this helps - there is a good tutorial [here](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2014/02/03/selenium-with-node-js/)

Comment: [Steps for Linux](//stackoverflow.com/a/24364290/1197421)

Comment: Why pollute your path with single project's requirements, when you can use `.setFirefoxService(serviceBuilder)`?

Comment: Fusion writing an answer to show people how to do that would help them.

Comment: Thank you, please remember that selenium-side-runner works with node 8 and 10

Answer (score 17):

Even after adding the driver path in the System variables it didnt worked.

But by creating & setting own default chrome service, it worked

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;

var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
.build();
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to have chromedriver downloaded with my `npm install` command so I installed `chromedriver` from npm by

`npm install --save chromedriver`

but then I was left with the question of how to set the path and I ended up in this question.

If you use this method as well, according with the [npm-chromedriver docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver#running-with-selenium-webdriver) you can do

```js
require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();
```

It does work as expected for me, notice that chromedriver is not imported by assigning the `require` result to a variable but just as is

Answer (score 4):

You only need to install `npm install selenium-webdriver`. Then download the chromedriver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

```
const path = require('path');
const { ServiceBuilder } = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const geckoDriverPath = path.join(__dirname, "geckodriver"); // or wherever you've your geckodriver
const serviceBuilder = new ServiceBuilder(geckoDriverPath);
const SeleniumDriver = await new Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setFirefoxService(serviceBuilder)
  .build();
```

Comment: Did using **geckodriver** for Chrome realy work? @Aditya

Comment: They used FireFox, not Chrome, as it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the browser driver in the same location that you store your code for execution.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my terminal was already opened before I set PATH. All solutions failed until I finally restarted the terminal.

Comment: Time to use Puppeteer mate, 6 years ago i had to use Selenium , but when puppeteer came out oh god the amount of time saved.

Answer (score -2):

Under MacOSX the issue is likely to be caused by a wrong expansion of ~ to the hme directory. Set an absolute path instead of relying upon ~ and it works; at least on my computer.