# I am creating a new laravel project using breeze that require the nodejs and npm

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I run the command `php artisan breeze:install`, then select `blade`. In the end, it shows me the following error:

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn c:\users\dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chromedriver
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelProjects\loginProject\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn c:\users\dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chromedriver ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-08T09_38_39_578Z-debug-0.log
```

Can anyone suggest to me what could the problem be?

Comment: I would recommend you to use WSL2, and not XAMPP, you will learn about Linux (you will use it more than you think) and you will have way less issues like this one. You can use [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail) if you have no idea how to set up a Docker environment

Comment: Sir I am using windows 10 OS right now and tried resolving this using the help of GPT as well but still facing this issue can you help me with this on windows 10

Comment: it has double slash on the path, can you open `node.exe` ? you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191142/selenium-nodejs-chromedriver-path) to download the chromedriver

Comment: yes sir I also think the double slash could be the error can you tell me how to resolve this @francisco

Comment: please check the variable in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10) is whitout a slash in the end ou double..

Comment: It seems you don't have `node.js` installed. What does this command return? `node -v`

Comment: It looks like that this line: `'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g'` was executed as single path to executable inside cmd.exe instead of actually executing separately `call` with all arguments.

Comment: So what could be the solution for that sir @BladeMight

Comment: @AssadUllah Somewhere inside php code, system call used quotes where it shouldn't have, I suggest reinstalling everything and trying out from start, since its not something that should be fixed from user side.